# enumeration values 'NSFetchedResultsChangeMove' and NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate' not handled in switch

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I get this warning:
enumeration values 'NSFetchedResultsChangeMove' and NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate' not handled in switch

Any ideas?

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler knows that NSFetchedResultsChangeType has four possible values, but your code only handles two of those.  If you know for sure that the other two will not occur, you can ignore the warning.  But it would be safest to include some code to handle these other values, either nothing or an NSLog to see if they do occur.  I would add

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
    NSLog(@"A table item was moved");
    break;
case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
    NSLog(@"A table item was updated");
    break;
```

into your switch statement.  EDIT: having checked the docs, I see that these two values are not used for Section changes, so you can either ignore the warning or add null case statements along the above lines to suppress the warning.

Comment: thanks for that! It must be a new thing (or at least new to me) never had any warnings before.

Comment: I realised later that I don't get this warning. Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Those warnings indeed are showing with Xcode 6, they were not present in Xcode 5.

Answer (score 16):

You can also add

```
        default:
        break;
```

to get rid of those warnings.

Comment: This is the right thing to do. Don't write useless lines of code. Actually, this is what you have to do in Swift since default is mandatory.